# Create embedded hsqldb in web-app directory

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, war, hsqldb

Is there way to create embedded HSQLDB inside my web-app directory (I want that the path to my data was this: "Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/db", but I don't want to specify an absolute path) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do that because if you redeploy your webapp you will blow away the database or some other weird behavior might happen.

What you can do is use the system property `${catalina.base}` and put it in your Tomcat directory somewhere (or even in the webapps directory like you want).

How you get access of the system property and apply to HSQLDB is dependent on how you startup it up. If your using Spring you can use the PropertyPlaceholder to configure HSQLDB's location.

Comment: "${catalina.base}" Thanks! this is what I was looking for